# Pre-image of an empty set for a non-bijective function

Tags: functions

Say I have a function $f:A\to B$ such that $f$ is not bijective in the sense that some elements in $A$ are not mapped to $B$. What would the pre-image of the empty set? Would it still be the empty set or would it be the empty set union with the ones in $A$ that are not mapped onto $B$?

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is not a function since it's not left-total, but it's a binary relation , in your example the problem is that you consider the preimage of an empty set (which can be a singleton), however this happens if the binary relation is not surjective (right-total) and has nothing to do with the domain of the binary relation, assume:
$$∃a∈A:∀b∈B: f(a)≠b$$
With this information we cannot say that the binary relation is not surjective, and hence we cannot say that the preimage of some $b \in B$ is empty,the only information that your assumption gives us is that we don't have a function.